# VBA change text to number format

Tags: excel, vba, text, format, numeric

In vba I want to do some replacement, but Excel breaks the format when see something like a number.

I need 2 kinds of replacements

First need:

```
Original Data      =>   Wanted Data   =>  Best Approach   
['4', 6, '4']      =>   4,6,4         =>  4#6#4
[1.5, None, None]  =>   1.5           =>  1.5##
[256, 256]         =>   256,256       =>  256#256
[None, '', None]   =>   ,,            =>  ##
[4, 4]             =>   4,4           =>  4#4
[None, '1.50']     =>   1.5           =>  #1.5
```

The wanted Data is impossible to obtain, because the wanted data 256,256 is automatically convert in 256.256

The approach is work fine for me, because I can do an split with # as a separator

```
With RNG
        .Replace What:="None", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="#"
        .Replace What:="[", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="]", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="'", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
End With
```

---

Second need (it will be only 1 float in the string):

```
Original Data   =>   Wanted Data      
[None, '1.5']   =>   1.5      (breaks into 1,5)                  
[1.50]          =>   1.50     (breaks into 1,5) 
0.9,            =>   0.9      (breaks into 0,9)      
0.6             =>   0.6      (doesn't break because any replaced has been made)

With RNG
        .NumerFormat = "@" 'Doesn't work, although I do not want it either text format
        .Replace What:="None", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="[", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="]", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="'", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
End With
```

Any idea for the second need?

The next option to solve the second need "works fine" but is too slowly (more than 10000 rows) and even block my Excel during the process

```
For Each CL In RNG
        CL.NumberFormat = "@"
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, ",", "")
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, "None", "")
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, "[", "")
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, "]", "")
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, "'", "")
        CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, " ", "")
Next CL
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What about splitting the value into two different cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the text format like so:

```
Sub Test()

Dim RNG As Range, CL As Range
Dim LR as Long

'Get last used row in your sheet and set range (use a different type of lookup for LR if you want.
LR = Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set RNG = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(LR, 16))

'Set values to text and replace values
With RNG
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Replace What:="[", Replacement:=""
    .Replace What:="]", Replacement:=""
End With

'Trim all values
For Each CL In RNG
    CL.Value = Replace(CL.Value, " ", "")
Next CL

End Sub
```

- Try to avoid `.select` and `Selection`
- Obviously change the RNG to your needs.

**NOTE:** If you don't care about the comma you could replace that with a "-"

```
Sub Test()

Dim RNG As Range
Dim LR As Long

'Get last used row in your sheet and set range (use a different type of lookup for LR if you want.
LR = Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set RNG = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(LR, 16))

'Set values to text and replace values
With RNG
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Replace What:="[", Replacement:=""
    .Replace What:="]", Replacement:=""
    .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="-"
    .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=""
End With

End Sub
```

In this case I don't think numberformat would be nesseccary at all.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for the reply. although the "Selection.NumberFormar = "@" enforce to keep the text format in the cell, the problem is still than when I have "256, 256" and delete the space, converting to "256,256", excel delete the coma (,) automatically thinking is a miles separator :(

Comment: @Angel, I am unable to reproduce this as on my machine this works like a charm. Can you got through line by line and tell me the value after the last replace. So before Cells(1 ,1) = STR, please look at the STR value (Debug.print STR)

Comment: Hi JvdV, it seems that using your method STR= Replace(STR, "[","") works fine (i haven't been able to try so much). The problem is that I want to do this replace in some columns with miles of rows, so I do Selection.Replace to all column instead cell by cell. I suppose is quickler with excel function Selection.Replace (as in my example) than doing cell by cell. But using Selection.Replace the text vell value is convert to number. Any idea?

Comment: @Angel, as Excel's strongest instinct is to convert anything that looks a bit like a number into a number, this appears to hard. The fastest way to achieve what you want is in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks JvdV. First way seems to work, i will try it. Seconds it still good, so I will change the split delimiter to convert into array, but it could be good as one

Comment: @Angel, if this helped your out please consider to mark the question as answered

Comment: Hi JvdV, trying I'm still having problems... in the example [1.5, ], when I replace "[" and "]" and "," and " ", excel autmatically put my 1,5 (change de dot by the comma) even if I put the NumberFormat = "@" this breaks me totally

Comment: @Angel, this should never occur with above code examples. In your example [1.5, ], there is no replace of the ",". Output will be "1.5," and Excel doesn't create a number out of this. With bottom piece of code you replace any "," by a "-" which will result in "1.5-" as output. Best is to update your question with your exact code, input data and output data so I can have a good look.

Comment: @Angel, I have looked at your update and unfortunately there is, as far as my knowledge goes, no way to speed this up even further. I will have to stick with my comment from June 28 at 8:34.

Answer (score 0):

You are Using replace function which is basically  belong from text category.So you can multiply your result with 1 or you can use value function.